# can an <small> be inside a <p> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have to do a semantic webpage from a pdf. Everything is going fine (not at all), but I have a footnote that doesn't fit in a resposive line-height. I want to put it inside a p tag, which works fine, but I don't know if that is good.

here's the code:

```
.text {
  padding-left: 8.5vw;
  padding-right: 8.5vw;
  padding-bottom: 10vw;
}

.text-column {
  padding-top: 10vw;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 4vw;
}

.text p {
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 2.7vw;
  line-height: 3vw;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 3vw;
  font-size: 2.12vw;
}

.footnote hr {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 33%;
  height: 0.2vw;
  margin-top: 4vw;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
  border-color: #000;
}

.footnote {
  font-size: 1.36vw !important;
  text-align: justify !important;
  line-height: 1em !important;
}

<article class="text text-column">
...

  <small class="footnote">
    <hr>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi tempore nostrum laboriosam laborum sed nulla
        quae libero distinctio consequuntur. Ut sint molestiae, placeat voluptatibus vitae repudiandae architecto nemo
        et in?
  </small>
</article>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**. In fact, [the MDN page for `<small>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small) *itself* showcases a `<small>` tag nested inside a `<p>` tag as its example:

```html
<p>This is the first sentence.
  <small>This whole sentence is in small letters.</small>
</p>
```

`<p>` is a [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) element, and `<small>` is a [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) element. Any phrasing content can go inside of any flow content. In addition to this, `<small>` is an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements), so will not break the flow of the content.

However, keep in mind that `<small>` sets the size one size smaller than the *default* text size on the page, so you may need to adjust it accordingly. This can be done by nesting `<small>` *within* `<small>`, as `<small>` is *also* a valid parent of `<small>` itself. Note that there *is* an equivalent [`<big>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/big), though this is obsoleted in favour of CSS' [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, According to Official document also allow it.
https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/footnotes.html